# Are mature trees as susceptible to mutation from exposure to radiation as seedlings?

Tags: botany, mutations

If a plant, say a ficus or a teak, as a sapling were exposed to radiation, and a tree of the same species were present at the same distance, which of the two would be more likely to mutate?

Comment: Aren't they all trees in the end, anyway?

Comment: Either is an ecosystem in itself.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, but I'm saying if you want to compare trees and plants you should have a true exemplar of each.

Comment: Erm )+: I don't have an example ...

Comment: Don't worry about it, then, it was just a suggestion.  See if you get any answers with it as is.

Comment: All trees are plants, I'll rephrase the question. Please let me know if it doesn't meet your intentions.

Comment: Ionizing radiation is harmful because of damage to genes. It's thus far more damaging, to everything, earlier in the development cycle; down to the point of the very first cell, where relatively small doses of radiation can render the *potential* organism non-viable (like killing the cell outright). Random mutations all over a tree are unlikely to amount to much

Comment: Ben raises a good point about this question actually - @Everyone are you interested in the effect of radiation on a single cell sampled from a large tree (compared to a single cell in a sapling), or on the organisms as a whole? If it is the whole organisms, Ben has the correct answer I believe; mutations (and thus radiation) will be less of a problem to a plant once it is larger, as any cutting of the plant could go on to form a new tree; each individual cell becomes less important. (See http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/do-trees-age-on-a-microscopic-level/ out of interest)

Comment: Depending on what plant/tree is concerned, I could also imagine things like bark absorbing some of the radiation  being emitted.

Comment: @Luke: The overall effect and any inheritable changes were what I had in mind.

Comment: @LanceLafontaine: Visualizing the bark as a radiation shield is a great idea! Anybody know whether it is possible/tested?