# What is Growing on These Tree Leaves? (Image)

Tags: species-identification, botany, ecology, mycology, trees

I found a seemingly diseased tree when I was out playing tennis yesterday... What is growing on this tree leaf? Is this a disease? If so, is it contagious? I have zero knowledge in botany, but I'm curious about what is happening to these trees. :) 
[image]

Comment: I'm just wondering if you still play tennis in that location to confirm if you see any [*Juniperous virginiana* (eastern red cedar)](http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=97) nearby.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is actually not a gall as [other answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/10004/16866) have suggested.
This is likely a fungus called **Cedar-apple rust ([*Gymnosporangium juniperi-virginianae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnosporangium_juniperi-virginianae))**.

The fungus only thrives in the presence of both *Juniperus virginiana* (Eastern red cedar) and apple (*Malus* spp.) trees.

The leaf in the picture belongs to some species of the apple genus and the growths are [aecia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aecium) of *G. juniperi-virginianae*. You can read about this interesting fungi through Rutger's Plant & Pest Advisory [here](http://plant-pest-advisory.rutgers.edu/3859/).

You can see a picture of the fungi [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Cedar_apple_rust_showing_stomata.jpg), and I've included Sabrina Tirpak's (Rutgers PDL) [photo](http://plant-pest-advisory.rutgers.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/aecia-on-apple-e1368285975597.jpeg) of its aecia below:

[image: Gymnosporangium juniperi-virginianae-Sabrina Tirpak]http://plant-pest-advisory.rutgers.edu/3859/

Below is a visual of the [telia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telium) of the rust fungus on *J. virginiana*:

[image: Ada Hayden G. juniperi-virginianae telia]

<sup>(Photo source: [Ada Hayden Herbarium](http://www.herbarium.iastate.edu/))</sup>

Comment: What a fascinating organism!

Comment: Right?! I've never seen the tentacled glob that grows on the Juniper

Comment: That's so cool :)

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, these look like [insect galls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall); which are reactions of plant tissue caused by parasitic insects (often wasps) laying eggs inside the leaf. I'm sure someone can answer in more detail, though!

Cf. [How do plant galls form?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/761/how-do-galls-form?lq=1)

Comment: Would the tree die because of this? Most of its leaves are growing "insect galls"...

Comment: I imagine that it depends on the galling species and tree species, but [most leaf galls don't hurt trees](http://lancaster.unl.edu/hort/nebline/galls.shtml)