# What kind of parasite is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, parasitology, agriculture

I found this strange disease on the leaves of a pear tree. I don't know the tree's species but I found it in South Turkey, 150 km from the Mediterranean. What causes this disease?

[image: pear leaves with orange spots and protruding white spikes]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! If you know this a pear tree then you do know the genus ([*Pyrus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pear)). 

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/10002/16866

Answer (score 3):

This is **pear rust** (*Gymnosporangium sabinae*).

[image]

It is fairly widespread in the northern hemisphere:
[image]

It is a fungal infection and affects pear trees from junipers. Pruning the affected nearby junipers can help control its spread.